# Unable to create separate log file for instances of a class which are running on their own threads separately - log4j2

Tags: java, server, network-programming, log4j, log4j2

sorry for asking such a common question, however I was not able to fix my issue after applying those solutions.

So basically, I have created a network which allows me to execute different servers on their own separate threads respectively. Now the thing is it's working perfectly except for it's logging.

> **What I want to achieve:** 
>   I want to have separate log file per server.. based on the id of that server, for example 
>   main.log , server1.log , server2.log , server3.log , server4.log , etc...

**What's currently happening?**
The two main approaches which I have tried:-

***Tried Option1:-*** 
Log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %l - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="AppMain" filename="logs/main.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %l - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
        <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${sys:logFilename}">
                <Route>
                    <File name="Rolling-${sys:logFilename}" fileName="logs/${sys:logFilename}.log" append="false">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %l - %msg%n"/>
                    </File>
                </Route>

                <!-- By having this set to ${ctx:logFileName} it will match when filename
                     is not set in the context -->
                <Route ref="Console" key="${sys:logFilename}"/>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="Console"/>-->
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="AppMain"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="ServerRouting" level="all" additivity="false">
            <!--            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>-->
            <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender"/>
        </Logger>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Server.java:-

```
public class Server {
    private static Logger logger;
    private long id;
    private SomeClass someClass;

    public Server(long id, SomeClass someClass) {
        this.id=id;
        this.someClass=someClass;
        System.setProperty("logFilename",  "server"+id);
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(Constants.DYNAMIC_SERVERS);
        this.someClass.setLogger(logger);
    }

   public void bindSockets(String servername, int port) throws IOException { /*Some functionality*/}

   public void start() throws IOException { /*Some functionality*/}

}
```

Constants.java

```
public class Constants {

    static {
        System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "log4j2.xml");
    }

    public static String APP_NAME = "AppMain";
    public static String DYNAMIC_SERVERS = "ServerRouting";

}
```

*Using this methodology - when I start 4 servers, I get:*

> main.log , server2.log , server3.log , server4.log 
>   However the internal entries are all mixed up , and no file for server1 (i.e. server1.log) is created

***Tried Option2:-*** 
Log4j2.xml
I replaced Routes block in earlier log

```
   <Routes pattern="$${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}">

        <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has value 'special' for key ROUTINGKEY. -->
        <Route>
            <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}" fileName="logs/${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}.log"
                         filePattern="./logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}-special-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%t] %p %c{3} - %m%n</pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true"/>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
                </Policies>
            </RollingFile>
        </Route>
    </Routes>
```

Server.java:-
What I changed here is that, instead of using System.setProperty(), I am using ThreadContext.put(), to send log file names to log4j2

```
public class Server {
    private static Logger logger;
    private long id;
    private SomeClass someClass;

    public Server(long id, SomeClass someClass) {
        this.id=id;
        this.someClass=someClass;
        ThreadContext.put("ROUTINGKEY", "server"+id);
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(Constants.DYNAMIC_SERVERS);
        this.someClass.setLogger(logger);
    }

   public void bindSockets(String servername, int port) throws IOException { /*Some functionality*/}

   public void start() throws IOException { /*Some functionality*/}

}
```

*Using this methodology - when I start 4 servers, I get: only these two files*

> main.log , ${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}.log
>   Instead of 4 , as mentioned in beginning.
>   Where, all the internal entries for all servers have been added to single file i.e. ${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}.log

***Conclusion***
Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? It would be a massive help.
New suggestions are obviously welcomed, and if there is ambiguity in my question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are 2 problems.

1. You declare the `logger` as `static` in the `Server` class and therefore are sharing the logger across all instances of this class.
2. The `LogManager.getLogger` method is not thread safe and must be synchronized when used this way.

Below is some sample code and configuration that is working for me:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class Server {
    private Logger logger;
    private long id;

    public Server(long id, Object lock) {
        this.id=id;
        ThreadContext.put("ROUTINGKEY", "server"+id);
        synchronized(lock){
            logger = LogManager.getLogger(Constants.DYNAMIC_SERVERS);
        }
    }

    public void doStuff(){
        logger.info("Server "+ id +" did some stuff");
    }
}
```

A class to start 4 servers in separate threads:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Object lock = new Object();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Server s = new Server(1,lock);
                s.doStuff();
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Server s = new Server(2,lock);
                s.doStuff();
            }
        });

        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Server s = new Server(3,lock);
                s.doStuff();
            }
        });

        Thread t4 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Server s = new Server(4,lock);
                s.doStuff();
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
            t4.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

For completeness, the Constants class:

```
public class Constants {

    public static String APP_NAME = "AppMain";
    public static String DYNAMIC_SERVERS = "ServerRouting";

}
```

and the log4j2.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %l - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="AppMain" filename="logs/main.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %l - %msg%n" />
        </File>
        <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}">

                <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has value 'special' for key 
                    ROUTINGKEY. -->
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}" fileName="logs/${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}.log"
                        filePattern="logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}-special-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
                        <PatternLayout>
                            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%t] %p %c{3} - %m%n</pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6"
                                modulate="true" />
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="Console"/> -->
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="AppMain" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="ServerRouting" level="all" additivity="false">
            <!-- <AppenderRef ref="Console"/> -->
            <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender" />
        </Logger>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Running the `Main` class above with the log4j2.xml on the classpath generates 5 log files - one for each server and the "main" log - and each server log contains the logs generated by that server only. The main log is empty since no events were routed there.

I hope this helps!

Comment: hey @D.B. , thanks alot. After comparing my actual project code with your example, that worked - and issues make sense. \n As there was another issue in my project, which was that I was creating instance of Server outside of the thread, and calling the run method from inside of it, in my main class, hence no wonder everything was getting dumped on one file. Along with the static issue you pointed out. Massive thanks :)